# When running node js file on command line not finding module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm extremely new to node.js and am begining to learn from w3Schools. When inserting the path of where my code is saved to the command line this error was shown: "Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\ahamo\myFirst.js' ". I used the command node myFirst.js

My file is saved in the documents section of my pc.

Comment: which command did you try and this error happened?

Comment: I used the node command

Comment: there is no the node command, so can you tell me exactly what you executed?

Comment: I am not quite sure because I am very new to node and was running a code from w3Schools

Comment: Here is the link to the website I was using [link](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_get_started.asp)

Comment: You need to navigate to the folder containing your .js file then type `node myFirst.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a few things that you should do/perform.

If something goes wrong along the way, let us know at which step and provide your keyboard input and the console output.

1. **Node installed:** Make sure node.js is installed:
   Run `node --version`. This should work in any directory and return your version.
2. **Correct path:** Navigate to your application's directory (using the `cd` command).
   *In your case: `cd C:\Users\<your username>\Documents\`* Alternatively, by navigating there in Windows Explorer and typing `cmd` in the address bar
3. **File exists and has correct extension:** To ensure that the file exists, please run `dir` in this directory. Ensure that the file only shows the file extension `.js`, not `.js.txt` or similar. *In your case, there should be an entry like this in the output of the `dir` command:

   `2018-08-21  11:15                 155 MyFirst.js`*
4. **Dependencies are installed:** Run `npm install` in that directory. This will install all (if any) dependencies defined in your manifest `package.json`. *In your case: Looking at the link you provided to the code you used, there aren't any dependencies. So you can skip this.*
5. **node is started correctly:** Run `node myFirst.js`. Alternatively, `node C:\Users\<your username>\Documents\myFirst.js` should also work.

Comment: I ran all of the above and here is what came up for my version I am using v10.9.0, for the installations there were none that were needed and after I ran node myFirst.js and the same error occurred. I tried saving the js file outside of the documents section (same folder which is my username) however the command line would just show nothing for a while.

Comment: Please run `dir` in the directory and let me know what the exact output is pertaining to your file myFirst.js.

Comment: @Ameer did you type `node` or `node myFirst.js`?

Comment: I typed `node myFirst.js`

Comment: @Ameer Did you run the `dir` command in the directory? Please ensure that the file has the correct file extension. Under certain circumstances, when saving files (e.g. with notepad), Windows appends .txt to the filename. Even if it already has a file extension.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the absolute path to your file.

It looks like it might be at `C:\Users\ahamo\Documents\myFirst.js`, but I can't tell without more information. Confirm where your file is located. Then execute node with the absolute path - for example:

1. `node C:\Users\ahamo\Documents\myFirst.js`; or
2. `node <absolute\path\to\file>`

Answer (score 0):

At first, check your code and install globally npm and node. Then create your file in this directory C:\Users\ahamo\myFirst.js and run node myFirst.js

Comment: All of your answers were useful however I can't accept all of them.

Comment: As you wish. Thanks